# CNN for classifying noise

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I have a dataset of images and the noise functions (and coefficients) that generate them.  I would like to train an AI such that it takes in the image and produces as a result what noise function and coefficients most closely match the image.

I've been exploring CNN's and image classification as a possible way to do this, but I'm not really sure if thats the correct approach. Is this a good way to go about this? Can I cross train an existing network for this type of functionality?

I don't have an amazing GPU and the last time I trained a GAN it took me months to get mediocre results.  I'm hoping to go down the correct path the first time on this experiment.

Comment: Can you describe the noise functions you have? Also with some math.